# Derive a function and then make a fast version for execution

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, timing

I would like to derive a (complicated) equation of motion and integrate it efficiently numerically.  I can do this "by hand" by copying the resulting function in a new function and then using that copy.  But how to do the copy automatically?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
f1[x_] := 
  Block[{U}, U = -Cos[x]; Pause[0.1] (* long derivation *); D[U, x]];
t1 = AbsoluteTiming[
    NDSolve[{x''[t] + f1[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == x'[0] == 1}, 
     x, {t, 0, 1}]][[1]];

f2[x_] := Sin[x];
t2 = AbsoluteTiming[
    NDSolve[{x''[t] + f2[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == x'[0] == 1}, 
     x, {t, 0, 1}]][[1]];

f3[x_] := f1[x]
t3 = AbsoluteTiming[
    NDSolve[{x''[t] + f3[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == x'[0] == 1}, 
     x, {t, 0, 1}]][[1]];

{f1[x], t1, f2[x], t2, f3[x], t3}
```

All three functions are "the same" (Sin[x]), but the copy (f2) is much faster to use than the derived version (f1 - the Pause simulates the derivation).  A naive copy (f3) does not avoid the derivation in f1. The timings here are arbitrary, to illustrate the problem.  On my machine t1 and t3 are about 100*t2. (Please do not suggest using `DSolve`.  The real equations of motion are complicated and have no analytic solution.)

So:  How can one define a suitable f3 using the result from f1 and have it run as fast as f2?

Comment: What about `f1[x_] =...` with `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`)?

Comment: Thanks!  This works for my simple example.  I will check to see if it works in the problem that inspired this post and comment again when I know more.

Comment: Things are murkier in my original code.  I got it to work, but not by replacing := with =.  But my code is a bit complicated to post, so let's close this by asking one more thing:  

If I change f1[x_]:= to f1[x_]=  ,  then t3 is consistently around 30% shorter than t1. (and even 10% faster than t2!)  Any ideas why?